# SAP ABAP: best way to do currency convertion for many single values in report

Tags: report, currency, abap

One of our customers has a z-programm to generate a simple report about specific kinds of orders. The reports show several values of calculated vbak-netwr entries. There are sums, subsums, and single entries in lists.

Those values are shown in the local currency of EUR. Now, they have to be displayed in US$ as well.

Here is a simplified example:

**Old**: 
*Value* 
1400 
1200 
...

**New**: 
*Value (EUR) | Value (US$)* 
1400.............| 1757 
1200.............| 1506 
...

I know, I can use CONVERT_TO_FOREIGN_CURRENCY to do display the new information.

However, I am concerned about how to convert all those values (single, sum, subsum, etc...). Call the function each time for each value and save it into an own variable? This seems to be rather slow and increases the reports complexity.

Are there other ways to convert and display many values at once?

Comment: are the subsums automated via `LOOP AT [...]. AT BEGIN OF[xxx]. WRITE [value]. ENDAT.  [...]` Or are the calculated in the report?

Comment: They are automated, like in your snippet.

Answer (score 2):

If all original amounts are in the same currency and there is only 1 target currency, how about calling CONVERT_TO_FOREIGN_CURRENCY once with 1 EUR to get the exchange rate (ex: 1 EUR = 1.26 USD) and then simply multiplying your amounts by the exchange rate (x*1.26) without re-calling the Function Module ?